# Passing a dictionary as a parameter to a thread function

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, thread-safety, parameterized

How is it possible to pass a dictionary as a parameter to a thread function and then iterate through it?

```
Dictionary<string, Track> dic = allTracks;
updateThread = new Thread(() => toDB(dic));
updateThread.Start();
```

and the function:

```
public static void  toDB( Dictionary<string, Track>  dict)
   {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Track> pair in dict)
        { 
          //do something - but I do not alter anything in dictionary 
        }
   }
```

I have tried like this but I get an error

> *Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.*

Comment: `foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Track> pair in dict.Values.ToList())` try that

Comment: @Rahul He should make the copy BEFORE passing the copy to the thread. If the collection is being modified outside the thread, the exception can still be thrown if the main thread modifies the dictionary while the `.ToList()` is executing if you do it inside the thread.

Comment: Well the collection IS modified outside the thread.Can you provide an example of making the copy outside in the main thread?

Comment: @jayt.dev So you will get that exception then. Unless you pass a copy to the thread.

Comment: i think collection modifies outside the thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get this exception if your dictionary is modified in the main thread or the thread you have passed on to. You can use [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) or implement the locking yourself.

However, if you do not intend to modify the original collection inside the function you are calling in the thread and you don't need the latest values either, then you can simple create a copy before passing it to your seperate thread.

Comment: How can I lock the dictionary or better just pass a copy of it to the thread function?

Comment: like this Dictionary<string, int> copy = new Dictionary<string, int>(dictionary);

Comment: @jayt.dev Just use `ConcurrentDictionary` - it manages all the locking for you. However, if the dictionary is small you could just pass a copy of it to the thread using `new Dictionary<string, Track>(dic)` - that constructor makes a copy of the dictionary passed to it.

Comment: The thing is that I tried passing a copy of the dictionary and I still get the error. Should i convert ToList() inside the thread as well?

Comment: if (updateThread.IsAlive==false)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, Track> copy = new Dictionary<string, Track>(allTracks);
                    updateThread = new Thread(() => toDB(copy));

Comment: Well I am not sure I understand why. toDB() doesn't return anything it is void. I first check if updateThread isAlive. If not it means that it has finished and I can pass again the dictionary to perform something. I don't need data from the thread. I need to pass data to the thread and wait for it to finish.. then pass again data to it